# How can I get access to the selfie mobile camera using HTML5 / JS?

Tags: android, ios, web, mobile, camera

I have designed like a border to let the user see himself in it, the user will open my site and the mobile selfie should work in anyway (idk the process) so their stream will be showing in that border.

I really want help!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You should try looking into `navigator.mediaDevices` elements in JS.

There is so much details to cover here, so I added some links to guides instead. If exploring `navigator.mediaDevices` don't works for you.

There's a test site here on CodePen: https://codepen.io/chrisbeast/pen/ebYwpX

And the guide with more details here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/front-and-rear-camera-access-with-javascripts-getusermedia

Comment: Thank you so much!! I need one more help with it, can you look on the line 8 on the JS code on https://codepen.io/chrisbeast/pen/ebYwpX? There is an error with me and it is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null`.

Comment: Weird. I don't get that error. Not on my laptop running chrome or my Android phone running chrome. All work good. Did you allow the website acces to the ressource? Could you have some sort of addon that "hides" your camera from the browser?

Comment: Hmm did you try on your mob?

Comment: I tried to test it there in codepen using my android, it is working But when I get the code and host it locally so it is not working on phone!

Comment: I assume it is because that my localhost doesn't have the secure lock badge?